# starkit fails to load a pkgIndex.tcl

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, starkit

I've released a Tcl/Tk application for Windows wrapped with sdx.

In myapp.vfs I have a library for which I have a pkgIndex.tcl file:

```
 myapp.vfs
 |
 +-- mylib
 |   |
 |   +-- pkgIndex.tcl
 |
 +-- main.tcl
```

Everything works fine for the vast majority of my users but some of them (less than 0,1%) reported that on their machine the application fails on startup.

From the error message they sent me, I can see that it hangs the first time I use a function that is in mylib.

If they try on a different machine, everything works fine.

The problem is that I've not been able to reproduce the error myself, one user had the programn failing on an XP system and running on a Win7/64, another one had it failing on 7 and running on Vista.

I've already checked their antivirus, their privileges and all the usual stuff with no success.

Consider that the application successully ran for thousands of users but those few.

The question is: under which circumstance the pkgIndex.tcl of one of the libraries within a starkit may (silently) fail?

Comment: The glib answer is “under no circumstance”. What is their system locale? (About the only thing I can think of — not knowing the starkit startup code well — is some weird problem with failing to mount the VFS, but then `main.tcl` ought to be missing too…)

Comment: I agree it's really strange: if the exe is not mounted, how is main.tcl executed?  Locale is the same for all the machines what makes you suspect of it?

Comment: You could try to instrument your pkgIndex.tcl, to see if it is loaded at all and just the source/load inside fails. If it is a C extension there might be some issue with dependent libraries that exist on one machine and are missing on another (zlib and libpng are typical candidates for something like that). Try to check with dependency walker where your dependencies come from if it is a binary extension.